# Real symmetric operators in $\ell^p$, for $p\neq 2$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the spaces $\ell^p$, for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Suppose we have a bounded operator $S: \ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ such that $S(\ell^p) \subseteq \ell^p$ for every $p \geq 1$ and such that $S$ restricted to $\ell^p$ is also a bounded operator into $\ell^p$.

Furthermore, assume that $S$ is symmetric in the sense that 
$$
\langle  S f, g \rangle =\langle  f, S g \rangle
$$
for every $f \in \ell^p$ and every $g \in \ell^q$, for $1\leq p < \infty$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual pairing between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$.

Lastly, assume $\overline{\big(Sf\big)}=S\big(\overline{f}\big)$, where $\overline{g}$ denotes the complex conjugate of the sequence $g$.

Question: have these type of operators been studied? In particular, what is known about their spectrum? For example: if $p=2$ is not hard to be convinced that $S$ is self-adjoint and hence has real spectrum. Is the same true for $p\neq 2$?

Comment: Is $S$ assumed linear?

Comment: You'd better ask this question on mathoverflow.

Comment: @C.Ding Yes. $S$ is linear.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: Is this all happening on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Also, can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "spectrum"? Like you want $S-\lambda Id$ to be invertible but on what domain and codomain?

Comment: @mathworker21No. The setup is $\ell^p$. The operators are all assumed to be bounded, so the domain and codomain are all assumed to be $\ell^p$ as well.